# Parameter 'id' cannot be empty - Infragistics combo box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm trying to create an Infragistics combobox within a MVC application.

Here's the code within the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h4>Choose a customer:</h4>
    <div id="table">
    @Html.Infragistics().ComboFor(item => Model)
        .ID("comboBox")
        .Width("270px").ID("customerCombo")
        .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("GetAllCustomerData", new { ibu = ViewBag.IBU }))
        .ValueKey("nat_acc_nbr")
        .TextKey("nat_acc_nbr")
        .ResponseDataKey(null)
        .DataBind()
        .Render();
    </div>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="query" />
}
```

And here is the GetAllCustomerData method within the controller:

```
    [AuthorizeEagleUser]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllCustomerData(string ibu)
    {
        bool authorized = SecurityCheck(ibu);

        if (authorized)
        {
            IQueryable<AllCustomersModel> customers = new AllCustomersData().fillModel(ibu);

            JsonResult result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = customers,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            return result;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

I have verified that the `fillModel` method (which contains and executes the actual SQL query) does work fine, as I have managed to create a basic HTML table using the data that was pulled using that method. Also, authorized does return true (for me) when I step through the code.

The `nat_acc_nbr` field is the primary key from the data pulled.

The problem is that I keep getting an ArgumentException on the `@Html.Infragistics` line, saying that "Parameter 'id' cannot be empty." I've tried to find where this id is located so I can populate it, but I cannot seem to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you've looked at the stored procedure declaration?  in the database?  please post the declaration of the procedure.

Comment: @TMcKeown - Are you talking about the `GetAllCustomerData` method within the controller?

Comment: Just a guess, but should ID be on it's own line here?

Comment: Meant to add it... still throws the same exception. Edited it in.

Comment: @TMcKeown - Edited in.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit vague but I think it generally stands for "I can't find the property of the model you defined". Essentially there are two ways to define a combo - strongly typed just like you can with any default editor for MVC (as you have seen in the [ASP.NET MVC Helper sample](http://igniteui.com/combo/aspnet-mvc-helper) and your code is trying to achieve using **ComboFor< TProperty >()**) and you can also do a combo that is not bound to your model. The expression you use assigns the entire model as property to use.. which I'm not sure can would work at all.

1) If you want strongly-typed combo (useful for form submits) you should have your model defined so the type can be inferred by the helper and you can select it:

```
@model AllCustomersModel
```

2) You are not binding to server-side data so DataBind() call is not needed.

3) If you want to use chaining on multiple lines you should wrap it in brackets:

```
@(Html.Infragistics().ComboFor(item => item.nat_acc_nbr)
   .ID("comboBox")
   .Width("270px").ID("customerCombo")
   .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("GetAllCustomerData", new { ibu = ViewBag.IBU }))
   .ValueKey("nat_acc_nbr")
   .TextKey("nat_acc_nbr")
   .ResponseDataKey(null)
   .Render())
```

4) If you don't need to submit forms with the combo, you could use a simple combo and skip the model declaration:

```
@(Html.Infragistics().Combo()
   .ID("comboBox")
   .Width("270px").ID("customerCombo")
   .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("GetAllCustomerData", new { ibu = ViewBag.IBU }))
   .ValueKey("nat_acc_nbr")
   .TextKey("nat_acc_nbr")
   .ResponseDataKey(null)
   .Render())
```

You also might want to have a look at the help docs: [Adding igCombo](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/jQuery/2013.2/CLR4.0?page=igCombo_Getting_Started.html)